# Ratio of the radii of two circles

Tags: geometry

This is a problem that I saw first many years ago in a recreational math website, and every person who commented proposed a different solution. I'm posting it here in the hopes that someone can illuminate me.

Let $A$ and $B$ be two circles of different radii that touch externally; let  $C$ and $D$ be two perpendicular lines, each tangent to both $A$ and $B$. What is the ratio of the radii of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: The down-vote and the vote to close are absurd.

Comment: Do you still have a link to the website where the problem was originally posted?

Comment: What do you mean by "someone can illuminate me"? Are you looking for yet another solution, do you not understand the solutions you were offered, or what?

Comment: Dasherman: I think I originally saw the problem here http://gaussianos.com/circunferencias-tangentes-y-rectas-perpediculares/ (in Spanish, unfortunately).

Comment: Rory Daulton: I mean that I stopped studying geometry in primary school, so I really can't figure out the solution. As in, if you give me time and access to a computer, I could write an iterative script that approximates the solution, but I'm curious to see how a real mathematician would approach this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the larger circle have centre $O$ and radius $R$ and the smaller have centre $P$ and radius $r$.

Then the configuration is constructed by taking two perpendicular tangents of the large circle and marking off the corresponding radii, creating a square of side $R$.

In the corner of the square and tangent to the large circle at $T$ sits the small circle, which relates to a similar square of side $r$.

Let $Q$ be the common vertex of both squares, which is the one most distant from their centres. Note that $OQ=R\sqrt 2$ and $PQ=r\sqrt 2$.

Computing the distance $TQ$ by reference to the large circle gives $TQ=OQ-OT=R\sqrt 2-R$

By reference to the small circle $TQ=TP+PQ=r+r\sqrt 2$

And $R(\sqrt 2-1)=r(1+\sqrt 2)$ is sufficient to determine the ratio.